# HKAnchoredObjectQuery updateHandler not being called

Tags: ios, healthkit

I have a `UITableView` backed by an `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`. My `resultsHandler` is called fine, but my `updateHandler` is never called. I am not looking for background delivery, just live foreground delivery when a new sample is added to the health store. According to the docs on the [updateHandler](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkanchoredobjectquery/1615691-updatehandler):

> If this property is set to nil, the anchor query automatically stops
>   as soon as it has finished calculating the initial results. If this
>   property is not nil, the query behaves similarly to the observer
>   query. It continues to run, monitoring the HealthKit store. If any
>   new, matching samples are saved to the store—or if any of the existing
>   matching samples are deleted from the store—the query executes this
>   update handler on a background queue.

I do set my `updateHandler` on the query, and there are being new samples written to the health store.

In my `viewDidLoad` I set up my query:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setup TableView
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let nextDay = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self.date)!
    let startOfNextDay = calendar.startOfDay(for: nextDay)

    let resultsHandler: HKAnchoredObjectQueryHandler = { [weak self](query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        guard let samples = samples as? [HKCorrelation],
            let _ = deletedObjects else {
                // Need error handling here
                return debugPrint("Query error occurred: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Get a reference to the query and anchor
            strongSelf.query = query
            strongSelf.anchor = anchor

            // Add new samples
            strongSelf.foodEntries = samples
            for entry in strongSelf.foodEntries {
                debugPrint(entry.metadata?[HKMetadataKey.mealOfDay] as! Int)
            }
        }
    }

    let updateHandler: HKAnchoredObjectQueryHandler = {[weak self](query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        guard let samples = samples as? [HKCorrelation],
            let deletedObjects = deletedObjects else {
                // Need error handling here
                return debugPrint("Query error occurred: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Get a reference to
            strongSelf.anchor = anchor
            print(#line, "HKAnchoredObjectQuery IS LONG RUNNING")
            // Add new samples
            strongSelf.foodEntries.append(contentsOf: samples)

            // Remove deleted samples
            let deletedObjects = deletedObjects
            for object in deletedObjects {
                if let index = strongSelf.foodEntries.index(where: {$0.uuid == object.uuid} ) {
                    strongSelf.foodEntries.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
            strongSelf.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    HealthManager.shared.anchoredFoodQuery(startDate: self.date, endDate: startOfNextDay, anchor: anchor, resultsHandler: resultsHandler, updateHandler: updateHandler)
```

}

The anchored object methods in my `HealthManager` are:

```
func anchoredFoodQuery(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, anchor: HKQueryAnchor? = nil, resultsHandler: @escaping HKAnchoredObjectQueryHandler, updateHandler: HKAnchoredObjectQueryHandler?) {
    let predicate = HKSampleQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: [.strictStartDate, .strictEndDate]) //NSPredicate(format: "date => %@ && date < %@", startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)
    guard let foodIdentifier = HKCorrelationType.correlationType(forIdentifier: .food) else {
        fatalError("Can't make food Identifier")
    }
    anchoredQuery(for: foodIdentifier, predicate: predicate, resultsHandler: resultsHandler, updateHandler: updateHandler)
}

/// Wrapper to create and execute a query
private func anchoredQuery(for sampleType: HKSampleType, predicate: NSPredicate?, anchor: HKQueryAnchor? = nil, limit: Int = HKObjectQueryNoLimit, resultsHandler: @escaping HKAnchoredObjectQueryHandler , updateHandler: HKAnchoredObjectQueryHandler?) {
    let query = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: sampleType,
                                      predicate: predicate,
                                      anchor: anchor,
                                      limit: limit,
                                      resultsHandler: resultsHandler)
    query.updateHandler = updateHandler

    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

Comment: Rather than adding an update to the question you should write an answer and then accept that.

Comment: Seemed like, while it was the solution, it was unrelated to my question. I'll change it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `UITableViewController` was in a `UIPageViewController`. `viewDidAppear()` on the `UITableViewController` does not get called when returning from the detail screen, so I assumed `viewDidDisappear()` would not get called as well and I was stopping the query in there. My assumption was wrong.

A question on where to stop long running `HKQuery`s: [Do HKQuery's need to be stopped in View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831643/do-hkquerys-need-to-be-stopped-in-view-controllers)